# MonoGame SpriteBatch.Draw() invalid arguments when there really aren't any invalid arguments?

Tags: c#, arguments, draw, monogame, spritebatch

I'm drawing a Sprite in MonoGame and I'm trying to use the Draw()-method with the overload that enables a SpriteEffect to be passed as an argument, but I get a red underline and it says:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle?, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color, float, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteEffects, float)' has some invalid arguments
```

Now, I have reason to believe that the console is lying. One of these reasons being the fact that it doesn't have any flipping invalid arguments.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, effect, 1f);
```

`Texture` is my local Texture2D-variable that is initialized in the contstructor. `destinationRectangle` is a Rectangle that is passed as a parameter to my own Draw()-function. `null` is pretty self-explanatory. This also applies to the next three arguments. `effect` is simply passed as a parameter and finally 1f is obviously 1f.

I understand that I have done something wrong here, I just can't understand *what* it is I have done wrong. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the word Texture as a variable name? Texture is an abstract class, like Stream. This means the compiler will see it and think you are referring to the Type 'Texture', rather than a variable. Try changing your texture name to something else. 'myTexture' would be fine for testing purposes.

Comment: Without seeing more code, all I can recommend is that you try hard-coding each value until you see which one is causing the error; ex, effect becomes SpriteEffects.None.